# chrome footer overlapping content eventhough clear:both used

Tags: css, google-chrome

My footer div is overlapping the content in chrome browser eventhough I have cleared it. Can someonone poin t me in the right direction with the css. Should I use an if is chrome javascript thing?

http://archibaldbutler.com/projects/roaming-giraffe/html/

Thanks

Comment: Is the footer supposed to be on the bottom of the page or on the bottom of that content area?

Answer (score 0):

If the footer is designed to be at the bottom of the page all the time, then do this:

```
.footer-bg {
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 996px;
    height: 192px;
    background-image: url('../html/images/footer-bg.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content-bg2 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:192px;
    width: 996px;
    height: 369px;
    background-image: url('../html/images/maincontent2bg.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: none;
}
```

if it is supposed to just be at the bottom of that content area then do this:

```
.footer-bg {
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 996px;
    height: 192px;
    background-image: url('../html/images/footer-bg.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate you are a star I am so greatful to people who just bosh out an answer when it takes me ageeees, Kind regards, Archie

Comment: out of curiosity, which was it one or two?